# setState array cause infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have lists of arrays created from sampling size. When I setState the array with the entire new array. I got an error of infinite loop.

**Code**

```
const sampleData = _.fill(Array(200), 0)
const [value, setValue] = useState(sampleData)

setValue(value.fill(100)) // Error
```

**Error**

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Is this a verbatim snippet of your component code?  Wouldn't this suggest that you are doing a new `setValue` at every render?

Comment: I am assuming you are putting this at the function level? would it improve if you wrapped it on onmount useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call setter functions returned from useState during renders. They either need to be called in hooks(useEffect, useCallback, useLayoutEffect) callbacks or in non render phases, like event handlers.

In this case, you can do something like this:

```
const sampleData = _.fill(Array(200), 0);
const [value, setValue] = useState(sampleData);

useEffect(() => {
  setValue(value.fill(100)); // Error
}, []);
```